# Singleton - multithreaded issue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, singleton, mutex

I've seen posts about this issue but I'm still trying to figure it out. Is this way alright for implementing a safe singelton? I'm using mutex, static member and return its reference.

```
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
mutex mtx;

class MySingleton {
private:
    MySingleton();
public:
    MySingleton& getInstance() {
        mtx.lock();
        static MySingleton instance;
        mtx.unlock();
        return instance;
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't need the mutex.

Comment: How are you going to create the instance you need to call `getInstance()`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this way alright for implementing a safe singelton?

It's overshoot. Just get rid of the mutex and write:

```
static MySingleton& getInstance() {
    static MySingleton instance;
    return instance;
}
```

The thread safe creation of `instance` is guaranteed when the function is called the 1st time.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010, then I should use the double-locking or the mutex? because using the mutex seems to be more convenient and readable than double-locking. thanks

Comment: @ErezShmiel With visual studio 2010, you don't have c++-11 access. Thus use double locking.

Comment: ok, so just to be sure: using the mutex as I wrote wouldn't be the good way, right?

Comment: @ErezShmiel It would have no effect regarding the `static MySingleton instance;` statement.

Comment: shouldn't this method be declared `static`?

Comment: @W.K.S Oops, sure of course.